# ¿como habilito el mutear audio de la pestaña de chrome para mi pagina web?

Tags: google-chrome

Estoy haciendo una web con audio de fondo, y en el chrome no puedo mutearlo desde el iconito de la pestaña, esto no pasa en otros navegadores, como en firefox, en firefox lo muteo desde la pestaña y funciona, pero en chrome, si bien me muestra el iconito del parlante (reconoce que hay un audio sonando) no me deja mutearlo, no hace nada cuando clickeo sobre el.

Alguna idea?

Saludos, Leandro.

Comment: Programas distintos tienen funcionalidades distintas. Firefox ofrece esa funcionalidad, Chrome no.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es un problema de programación.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En Chrome debes hacer click derecho sobre la pestaña y seleccionar la opción silenciar pestaña.